# Unknown Class and Method in Caffeine Cache Manual Population Example

Tags: caching, caffeine

What is the Graph class and createExpensiveGraph() method in the Manual Population example of Caffeine Cache:

```
Cache<Key, Graph> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .maximumSize(10_000)
    .build();
// Lookup an entry, or null if not found
Graph graph = cache.getIfPresent(key);
// Lookup and compute an entry if absent, or null if not computable
graph = cache.get(key, k -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
// Insert or update an entry
cache.put(key, graph);
// Remove an entry
cache.invalidate(key);
```

https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population

?

Comment: They are there for example purposes. You use your own.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  That's what I thought, but was just wanting to be sure.